# log4cxx visual studio 2010 configuration release x64

Tags: c++, log4cxx

I have a console application with visual studio 2010 that uses log4cxx, the application with configuration debug x64 works well, the problem is that in Release x64 log4xcc throws this error:

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP120D.dll File: C\Program Files (x86)\Micrososft Visual Studio\12.0\VC\include\xstring Linia:79

Expression: string iterator not dereferencacle

Looking through internet I have not found any project with the log4cxx that it works with configuration release x64, any solution for my problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Blind guess: If a *release* compile makes a *debug* assertion fail, I'd suspect broken project settings, because the debug assertion *should* be deactivated. Perhaps `DEBUG` defined somewhere still?

Comment: Looking at my (10.0) includes, this check is only enabled `#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2`, which shouldn't happen in release. But the message *does* raise some questions about the code triggering it. You *should* double-check the iterator in question... (and no, I don't think the problem is in log4cxx, but without the *triggering* code it's hard to say). Perhaps you're looking at an unitialized value somewhere that *happens* to work in Debug because it's zero-initialized or somesuch. (MSVC is not my home turf, I'm still just guessing.)